# iOS app data in not transferring to Watch App

Tags: swift

I have worked on Watch app. for me everything is working as expected but when other developer is testing the watch app, iOS app data is not trasnferring and hence they are not able see anything in watch app. I don't know why is it happening why iOS app data is not transferring for them.

Comment: If you are working with CoreData then it's local to the device that you are testing. If you want the data to be shared then you should consider using iCloud or other similar solutions.

Comment: I am using realm